# How to append HDFS data into a Hive table with Zeppelin and R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin, hue

Here is my scenario; I have a Hive table that contains data. I want to be able to pull a new .xlsx file from a HDFS folder and append that data into the Hive table using Zeppelin and R.

I have gotten my program to be able to read the .xlsx file from HDFS using %spark.r and read_excel.

My question is: How can I transform and merge (append without duplicating) my new HDFS data into my Hive table?

Any help is much appreciated!!